# I have two different versions of VLC, how to remove?

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, snap, software-uninstall, flatpak

After I upgraded to 18.04 I removed unused apps, old packages and other cruft through the Software store and through the terminal. I found that VLC did not match yaru/communitheme I'm using so I tried some things suggested on the Arch Wiki and I also installed the VLC snap from the store. I now have VLC 3.0.4 and it matches the theme, confusingly though I also still have VLC 3.0.3 though I uninstalled it through the store and checked with apt/dpkg.

According to the store there is only one version of VLC installed. How do I remove the other one and where did it come from?

```
$ snap list --all
Name                  Version    Rev   Tracking  Publisher       Notes
canonical-livepatch   8.0.2      41    stable    canonical*      disabled
canonical-livepatch   8.0.3      42    stable    canonical*      -
canonical-livepatch   8.0.1      39    stable    canonical*      disabled
communitheme          0.1        961   stable    didrocks        -
core                  16-2.35    5328  stable    canonical*      core
core                  16-2.33.1  4917  stable    canonical*      core,disabled
core                  16-2.34.3  5145  stable    canonical*      core,disabled
core18                0.1        19    stable    canonical*      base
gnome-3-26-1604       3.26.0     70    stable/…  canonical*      -
gnome-calculator      3.30.0     222   stable/…  canonical*      -
gnome-characters      3.28.2     117   stable/…  canonical*      -
gnome-logs            3.28.2     40    stable/…  canonical*      -
gnome-system-monitor  3.28.2     54    stable/…  canonical*      -
gtk-common-themes     0.1        319   stable/…  canonical*      -
keepassxc             2.3.4      49    stable    keepassxreboot  -
keepassxc             2.3.4      40    stable    keepassxreboot  disabled
keepassxc             2.3.4      39    stable    keepassxreboot  disabled
vlc                   3.0.4      555   stable    videolan*       -
$ dpkg -l vlc
dpkg-query: no packages found matching vlc
$ grep -i vlc ~/.local/share/applications/*.desktop
$ grep -i vlc /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
$ whereis vlc
vlc: /snap/bin/vlc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here is the embarrassing part: I also installed the flatpak runtime from the PPA and now I remember that I tried the [flatpak VLC](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.videolan.VLC) but it didn't integrate well with 16.04, so I forgot about it (hoping that it might improve in the future).

```
$ flatpak list
Ref                                             Options       
org.videolan.VLC/x86_64/stable                  system,current
org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/1.6 system,runtime
org.freedesktop.Platform.ffmpeg/x86_64/1.6      system,runtime
org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Ambiance/x86_64/3.22          system,runtime
org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Communitheme/x86_64/3.22      system,runtime
org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.11                    system,runtime
$ find /var/lib/flatpak/app/org.videolan.VLC/ -iname *.desktop
/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.videolan.VLC/x86_64/stable/3aa719dda459ee693de4d94cee23e50e2f6eb144d1914d3bc93a15a6e8ba762b/files/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/vlc-openvcd.desktop
/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.videolan.VLC/x86_64/stable/3aa719dda459ee693de4d94cee23e50e2f6eb144d1914d3bc93a15a6e8ba762b/files/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/vlc-opendvd.desktop
/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.videolan.VLC/x86_64/stable/3aa719dda459ee693de4d94cee23e50e2f6eb144d1914d3bc93a15a6e8ba762b/files/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/vlc-openbd.desktop
/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.videolan.VLC/x86_64/stable/3aa719dda459ee693de4d94cee23e50e2f6eb144d1914d3bc93a15a6e8ba762b/files/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/vlc-opencda.desktop
/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.videolan.VLC/x86_64/stable/3aa719dda459ee693de4d94cee23e50e2f6eb144d1914d3bc93a15a6e8ba762b/files/share/applications/org.videolan.VLC.desktop
/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.videolan.VLC/x86_64/stable/3aa719dda459ee693de4d94cee23e50e2f6eb144d1914d3bc93a15a6e8ba762b/export/share/applications/org.videolan.VLC.desktop
```

To remove just run:

```
flatpak uninstall org.videolan.VLC
```

For flatpak integration with Gnome Software install the respective plugin:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
```